# How to Sync Autoincrement value of Hibernate

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I am using Hibernate4 and Table id field set as auto-increment bow us.

I have a scenario like this: suppose 3 persons came to my side to registration and last userregistrationid=2. Now three users come, the first user will get userid=3 (as it is auto-incremented by hibernate) but this user is not registered, so if another user will come for registration again, he will get same registrationid=3.

One user can be able to register, and one will fail. Now how to resolve such type of issue?

Comment: This is not a SO question. Since you do not have a problem in code, but are looking for an algorithm, or concept, you might want to ask differently, and/or elsewhere, maybe in the programming SE site.

Comment: How to migrate this quetion